# How to make middle div higher than first and second

Tags: html, css

I have three divs and I want the middle div to be higher than other two.

I tried using top:-50 for the second div, but it didn't work.

```css
.cards {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 31%;
    margin: 0 1% 2% 1%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    .card {
        flex: 0 0 48%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .card {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: column of three divs center one is higher]

Comment: pst. it would be "How to make middle div higher than first and second." :)

Comment: What do you mean by higher though? There are a few ways to adjust positioning of elements on a page. You could use relative positioning and margins or absolute positioning. You could even use the vertical-align css property.

Comment: @nstanard Opps I forgot to check for typos lol. Please look at the image below and you will know what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: perhaps put the middle square div in a div and give it a class which raises it a bit?

Comment: oh ok.. coming right up

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. It uses flexbox properties you should be familiar with. Dont rely on margins! If it's helpful please upvote and accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using flexbox! Don't rely on margins.

codepen: https://codepen.io/nstanard/pen/gqYrjZ

```
    .cards {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 350px;
        justify-content: bottom;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .card {
        flex: 0 0 31%;
        margin: 0 10px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .card:nth-child(2) {
        align-self: flex-start;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
        .card {
            flex: 0 0 48%;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
        .card {
            flex: 0 0 100%;
        }
    }
```

```
<div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
    </div>
```

snippet:

```css
.cards {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 350px;
    align-items: center;
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 31%;
    margin: 0 1% 2% 1%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    .card {
        flex: 0 0 48%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .card {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue now is that the divs are no longer centered because you got rid of justify-content:center;

Answer (score 1):

for second div use margin-top and margin-bottom is -50px it will works...

so use this class

```
.card:nth-child(2){
  margin:-50px 0;
}
```

```css
.cards {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top:60px;
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 31%;
    margin: 0 1% 2% 1%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

.card:nth-child(2){
  margin:-50px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    .card {
        flex: 0 0 48%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .card {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
    </div>
```